# Calculating standard deviation given mean and a range mean values that correspond to z-scores

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution

When going over a stats review in my higher level engineering course I came across a problem I think I know how to solve but things are not adding up.

The problem is
"Assume that the average time of a prototype endovascular stent is 19 months, and that 60% of stents lasts 17 to 24 months, and that their age follows normal distribution. Find the standard deviation of the distribution"

What I've done so far
2 months before  μ (17-19 = 2 before ) and 5 months after  μ (24-19 = 5 after)
I took each percentage of before and after (2/7 months total (before) and 5/7 months total (after) to get 28.571% (before) and 71.4286% (after)

Knowing that percentage i then multiplied the before and after percents by the total 60% that is made by that range so:

before = 28.571% * 60% = 17.143%

after = 71.4286% * 60% = 42.857%

Knowing that I can find z-scores knowing that .5 -.17143 = .32857 (32.857%) comes before the start of the 60% and 1-(.5+.42857) = .07143 (7.143%) after the end of the 60%

I then used standard normal probabilities sheet to calculate the corresponding z-score and got

Zlow = -0.445
Zhigh = 1.465

Lastly I plug the z-score in to the formula z = (x- μ)/σ

-0.445 = 17-19/(σ) 
σ = 4.494 months

1.465 = 24-19/(σ)
σ = 3.413

This doesnt makes sense to me since the σ should be the same for both the low and high z-score. I've triple checked what I did and can't seem to find out where I went wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What justified your first step of assuming the proportions under and over must be 2:5?  (The zeroth step of your triple check should be to draw a picture of the Normal density curve and the areas represented by quantities in the problem.)

Comment: @whuber's hint is a good one. If you don't need to show this by explicit formula, you can easily get the right answer by using Excel's goal seek to find the standard deviation once you draw that picture and figure out what you know (and don't!)